# Expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, enumeration

when I try the following code in iOS for fast enumeration...

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                  @"Hefeweizen", @"IPA", @"Pilsner", @"Stout", nil];

for (NSString *element in array) 
    NSLog(@"Beer: %@", element);
```

... I get this error:

```
Expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure this is where the error occurs? Are you sure you're using Obj-C?

Comment: Mmm.. beer. Could really use a cold one!

Comment: Is Objective-C 2.0 disabled in some way? Maybe check you compiler settings.

Comment: Are you using the proper version of the compiler?  If you're using the command line, what is the output of `your_compiler_name --version`?  If you're using Xcode, what compiler is your project set up to use?

Comment: When I try gcc --version, I get this: melissa-amoros:build love$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: I am using a .m file, and objective C syntax and that is working.

Comment: I just tried this exact code in Xcode 4.1 without any problems whatsoever.  Should, per chance, you be using the beta release of 4.2 suggest you take any errors with a pinch of salt and try again in 4.1.

Comment: I have this problem in XCode 5.1.1, I've tried to put fast enumeration in category.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is called *fast enumeration* and is part of Objective-C 2.0, so if you're running a pre-2.0 version of the compiler it won't work.

The standard syntax which it sounds like the compiler is expecting is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    NSString *element = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog (@"Beer: %@", element);
}
```

Comment: How do I know what version of Objective C I am running? when I go into the project settings, what do I need to look for? Did you see my compiler version comment above? thanks

Comment: From the Objective-C runtime programming guide on developer.apple.com:

iPhone applications and 64-bit programs on Mac OS X v10.5 and later use the modern version of the runtime.

Other programs (32-bit programs on Mac OS X desktop) use the legacy version of the runtime.

You could also look at the file objc-api.h which defines OBJ_API_VERSION based on the current Mac OS version.  That file is located in the /usr/include/objc directory.